# Exclude a WordsPress snippet's functions to execute on a certain page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to prevent a function redirecting to the previous page after logging in to execute on my WooCommerce `/checkout` page, as it causes an error.

Here is the function (added to the functions.php file of my theme via the Code Snippet plugin):

```
/*
* Add a hidden field to our WooCommerce login form - passing in the refering page URL
* Note: the input (hidden) field doesn't actually get created unless the user was directed
* to this page from a single product 

*/
function redirect_user_back_to_product() {
  // check for a referer
      $referer = wp_get_referer();
    // if there was a referer.. 
    if( $referer ) {
      $post_id = url_to_postid( $referer );
      $post_data = get_post( $post_id );
      if( $post_data ) {
        // if the refering page was a single product, let's append a hidden field to redirect the user to
        if( isset( $post_data->post_type ) && $post_data->post_type == 'product' ) {
          ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="redirect-user" value="<?php echo $referer; ?>">
          <?php
        }
      }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_login_form', 'redirect_user_back_to_product' );

/*
* Redirect the user back to the passed in referer page
* - Which should be the URL to the last viewed product before logging
*/
function custom_woocommerce_login_redirect_back_to_product_page( $redirect, $user ) {
  if( isset( $_POST['redirect-user'] ) ) {
    $redirect = esc_url( $_POST['redirect-user'] );
  }
  return $redirect;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'custom_woocommerce_login_redirect_back_to_product_page' );
```

When logging in on the WooCommerce `/checkout` page, I get this error:

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function custom_woocommerce_login_redirect_back_to_product_page(), 1 passed in /homepages/8/d123456789/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 294 and exactly 2 expected in /homepages/8/d123456789/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/snippet-ops.php(469) : eval()'d code:36 Stack trace: #0 /homepages/8/d123456789/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(294): custom_woocommerce_login_redirect_back_to_product_page('https://www.web...') #1 /homepages/8/d123456789/htdocs/wp-includes/plugin.php(212): WP_Hook->apply_filters('https://www.web...', Array) #2 /homepages/8/d123456789/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php(979): apply_filters('woocommerce_log...', 'https://www.web...', Object(WP_User)) #3 /homepages/8/d123456789/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(292): WC_Form_Handler::process_login('') #4 /homepages/8/d123456789/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(316): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #5 /homepages/8/d1234 in /homepages/8/d123456789/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/snippet-ops.php(469) : eval()'d code on line 36
```

I tried adding a `if ( is_page('checkout') return;` condition, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is getting called with to few parameters you can resolve the error by adding the amount of parameters that the filter should pass as follows.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'custom_woocommerce_login_redirect_back_to_product_page', 10, 2 );
```

edit:

you can use something like this to compare the post_id

```
function redirect_user_back_to_product() {
  // check for a referer
      $referer = wp_get_referer();
    // if there was a referer.. 
    if( $referer ) {
      $post_id = url_to_postid( $referer );

      $checout = wc_get_page_id( 'checkout' );
      if($post_id === $checout) return;

      $post_data = get_post( $post_id );


      if( $post_data ) {
        // if the refering page was a single product, let's append a hidden field to redirect the user to
        if( isset( $post_data->post_type ) && $post_data->post_type == 'product' ) {
          ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="redirect-user" value="<?php echo $referer; ?>">
          <?php
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's preventing the error! Would you know how to avoid the function being executed on the page? I tried to write `if ( is_page('checkout') return;` on the first line and it doesn't work.
When I wrap the whole snippet with a condition, it doesn't work either:

`if ( ! is_page('checkout') {
[...]
}`

Comment: you can compare the Page ID of the `$referer` against the page ID of the checkout page